# WEBRick doesn't start up, throwing Invalid argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to start WEBRick for my local developement without any success. Below is the error message that i am getting. Any insight on why it might be failing?

Thanks

```
C:\Sites\ThinkBlog\crumblr&gt;rails s
=&gt; Booting WEBrick
=&gt; Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development
=&gt; Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=&gt; Notice: server is listening on all interfaces .
=&gt; Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `initialize': Invalid argume`enter code here`nt - ${::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml (Errno::EINVAL)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `open'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `load_file'
from C:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/abook.rb:1:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
```

Comment: can you show your facebook.yml code ?

Comment: developement:
 facebook_api_key: 281723125356234
 facebook_api_secret: c8cdcaae6b160cf204e18b32423qwew23

Comment: That's all i have in my facebook.yml code.

Comment: The source of the error seems to be C:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/abook.rb . Can you please show its contents?

Comment: Please show your config/initializer/abook.rb.

Comment: check the indentation of code.

Comment: Also check that the string you're passing to YAML.load_file is enclosed in double quotes ("), not single quotes (') - you're using interpolation there.

Comment: FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("${::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]

Comment: Above is the content of abook.rb file

Comment: It is so obvious when you notice it. :) You interpolate with a hash sign, not dollar. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks didn't notice that one. :) I will update it and try one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have interpolated your string incorrectly, the interpolation starts with hash sign (`#`), not dollar.

You need either to change this string to:

```
 FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

Or do it without interpolation at all:

```
sth = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join 'config', 'facebook.yml')
```

Comment: I am using double quotation mark. FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("${::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]

Comment: C:\Sites\ThinkBlog\crumblr&gt;rails s
=&gt; Booting WEBrick
=&gt; Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=&gt; Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=&gt; Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=&gt; Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/devise.rb:235:in `block in &lt;top (required)&gt;': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from

Comment: Please edit the question and put the new error and log lines in a code block. Or start a new question if this new error is totally unrelated to the one mentioned in this question. Btw the error message specifically points where the problem is. Line 235 of config/initializers/devise.rb Looking there would help.

Comment: @Chuchoo - This is completely new error. Consider this issue fixed and post a new question.

Comment: Exiting
C:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/devise.rb:235:in `block in &lt;top (required)&gt;': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:292:in `setup'
from C:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'

Comment: I am getting 90 minutes Post limitation error..I will post little later on..Thanks